# How to remove required attribute from element using only Javascript when radio button is unchecked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button named 'Other/Query' and when it is checked, the textarea below it becomes required using the required attribute.

I would like to remove the required attribute from the textarea element when the 'Other/Query' radio button is unchecked, using only JavaScript.

Is it possible to remove the required attribute when a radio button is unchecked?

I am currently using the JS below which adds the required attribute, but does not remove it when unchecked.

```
var gquery = document.getElementById("genquery");
var comment = document.getElementById("comments");
    gquery.addEventListener('change', function(){
    comment.required = this.checked;
});
if(gquery.required = false){
    comment.required = false;
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/alfrcr/wrqdL6jh/

Comment: @AlfredCrosby, You don't need the two `comment.classList.add`/`.remove` lines actually, just change the CSS rule into `textarea[required="required"]` [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wrqdL6jh/2/)

Comment: yeah that looks better and cleaner @Mi-Creativity

Comment: First of all use == or === when you checking the value, please correct your code. Then you can simple remove elemnt attributes by 'removeAttribute'.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the options given to me worked. I can see that you used a checkbox; however, I am using a radio button. I wish to remove the required attribute when a user selects another radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
gquery.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if (this.checked) {
    comment.classList.add('required')
    comment.setAttribute('required', 'required')
  }
});

genquerytwo.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(this.checked) {
    comment.classList.remove('required')
    comment.removeAttribute('required')
   }
});
```

See it in action -> [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohit0094arora/fk0hmgvs/2/)

Updated fiddle -> [**Updated Fiddle(v2)**](https://jsfiddle.net/fk0hmgvs/9/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it was unsuccessful.

I am using radio buttons, not checkboxes. I can add the required attribute to the textarea element, but I still cannot remove it when I select another radio button.

The purpose of this is to allow the user to select another radio button if they selected the Other radio button by mistake. Giving them the option to not add a required comment.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help, but it doesn't work with multiple radio buttons: I have 6 in total. Only one radio button should add the required attribute. If I click on any of the other 5 radio buttons, this should remove the attribute. I declared a variable for a class name, but it was unsuccessful. I have also hard-coded the required attribute to each of the input tags of the radio buttons. Do you think that's part of the problem?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle according to your condition. Also, can you please share your code so that I can take a look at it and try to figure out your problem?

Comment: Thanks, Mohit. I used your code, but it's long. Is there a way to shorten it, please?

Comment: @GrahamO'Mahony I have updated the fiddle with even shorter code.
I hope it solves your problem now.

**Please upvote this and mark it as solution if it solves your problem.**